# Client and server side password strength validation library

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, passwords

I'm trying to find a library for .Net which will allow me to validate a user-entered password, and check its strength.

I've found lots of links and recommendations for client-side implementations (mostly jQuery) and also examples of how to implement checks server-side.

However, since its best-practice to validate both client-side and server-side for user submitted data, I'm trying to find something which covers both. Otherwise I will have to keep the two implementations in sync if any changes are made.

Is there anything that would provide this symmetry, or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: Did you take a look at this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/145266/ASP-NET-Password-Strength-Indicator-using-jQuery-a

Comment: @christiandev Thanks, I hadn't seen that - looks like it covers shared rules, so could be very useful!

Comment: I moved it to an answer, in case others need it.